# Number of k-combinations for all N

Tags: algorithm, go

I'm attempting to write an algo that returns an array of all possible combinations for values 0, 1, and 2 for length n.

For example where n = 2:

```
00

01

02

10

11

12

20

21

22
```

Code that I have started but far from right or finished:

```
func main() {
    var results []string
    matches := rangeSlice(2)

    for a := 0; a < len(matches); a++ {
        for b := 0; b < 3; b++ {
            matches[(len(matches) - a) - 1] = b
            results = append(results, strings.Join(convertValuesToString(matches), ""))
        } 
    }

    printResults(results)
}
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please share some code, and try to be specific about the problem you have.

Comment: @oren updated original post. The algo needs to move left and right depending on the value so that I end up with the correct combo at the end. Just having a hard time coming up with a solution.

Comment: Does it need to be super efficient? If not I think the conceptually easiest thing is to write a recursive function f(n) which looks at the array from f(n-1) and for each string in the array generates three new strings by appending 0, 1 or 2 to the end, then returns the array formed by all of these new strings. Of course this can be made non recursive.

Comment: @countingstuff: I have to say that I found that comment ironic given that nick, since the answer is simply to count.

Answer (score 3):

This is just counting (in base *k*). You could do just that --convert consecutive integers to base *k* -- but that's a lot of divides and remainders, so you might as well use a simpler approach.

1. Start with *n* 0s, and then repeat as many times as you can:
2. Change all the trailing *k*-1 to 0, then add 1 to the previous element. If there is no previous element, you're done.

If it helps to understand, you could try this with *k*=10, which is ordinary decimal counting. Eg:

- 3919 → change trailing 9 to 0, add one to 1, result 3920
- 3920 → no nines at end, add one to 0, result 3921
- ...
- 3999 → change three trailing 9s to 0, add one to 3, result 4000

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of rici's solution (counting).  (Output is in the form of a 2D slice, each slice a combination.)

To produce your example output, `getCombinations(3, 2)`.

```
func getCombinations(base, length int) [][]int {
    // list of combinations always includes the zero slice
    combinations := [][]int{make([]int, length)}
    current := make([]int, length)
    for {
        incrementIndex := length - 1
        // zero trailing <base - 1>'s
        for current[incrementIndex] == base-1 {
            current[incrementIndex] = 0
            incrementIndex--
            // stop when the next digit to be incremented is "larger"
            // than the specified (slice) length
            if incrementIndex < 0 {
                return combinations
            }
        }
        // increment the least significant non-<base - 1> digit
        current[incrementIndex]++
        // copy current into list of all combinations
        combinations = append(combinations, append([]int{}, current...))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !

**Code :**

```
n = int(input("Enter value of n :"))
result=[]
for num1 in range(0,n+1):
    for num2 in range(0,n+1):
        result.append(str(num1)+str(num2))
print(result)
```

**Output :**

```
Enter value of n :3                                                                                                    
['00', '01', '02', '03', '10', '11', '12', '13', '20', '21', '22', '23', '30', '31', '32', '33']
```

Comment: I dont think that what the OP intended to have - `n` should be the number of char in every string where `k` is the range where the possible char are from. Your double for-loop allow n=2 only...